# How to parse a ValueError in Python without string parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, valueerror

I am running a programming and getting an expected ValueError output of:

`ValueError: {'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'}`

I cannot figure out how to parse this data and just take the code (or message) value. How can I just get the `code` value of the ValueError?

I have tried the following:

- `e.code`

  - `AttributeError: 'ValueError' object has no attribute 'code'`
- `e['code']`

  - `TypeError: 'ValueError' object is not subscriptable`
- `json.loads(e)`

  - `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'ValueError'`

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

### Edit

The one thing that *does* work is taking the string index, but I do not want to do this, as I feel it is not very pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) exception class have an [`args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args) attribute *which is `tuple` of arguments given to the exception constructor*.

```
>>> a = ValueError({'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'})
>>> a
ValueError({'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'})
>>> raise a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: {'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'}
>>> dir(a) # removed all dunder methods for readability.
['args', 'with_traceback']
>>> a.args
({'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'},)
>>> a.args[0]['code']
-123
```

Answer (score 1):

ValueError is a dict type. 
So you can use
    e.get("key")
to reach any field inside dict.

Comment: I see. Thank you. `get` seems to not work, as `AttributeError: 'ValueError' object has no attribute 'get'`. @Abdul answer worked well for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your `values()` directly from your dictionary not `e`. Try this one:

```
try:
     ValueError= {'code': -123, 'message': 'This is the error'}
     Value = ValueError.get('code')
     print Value
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Comment: I am simply using an `except ValueError as e`. I am not creating the dict itself. _I believe_ it comes from the API I am calling. If I cannot edit the `"`, is there another way to do this?

Comment: I see. Thank you. `get` seems to not work, as `AttributeError: 'ValueError' object has no attribute 'get'`. @Abdul answer worked well for my situation.

Comment: You should avoid `ValueError` name because that's a **Built-in Exceptions** name.

Comment: What should I use instead and where? Should I be saying `except error as e` or something like that? I thought you were supposed to `except (errorname)`? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: You can simply rename it. Because names like `ValueError`, `list` won't confuse the interpreter but it may confuse people reading your code. However in your case your reading directly from API.

Comment: @mypythonquestions The `try` and `except` block in Python is used to catch and handle exceptions. Python executes code following the try statement as a “normal” part of the program. The code that follows the except statement is the program’s response to any exceptions in the preceding try clause. You are using `try and except` method but you're trying to retrieve your 'code' value(-123) by using `except ValueError as e`, which `e` here is not that dictionary(your data structure) it's just an error.